# Creatures eat everything and wreck the house?

Tags: identification-request

There’s a children’s book with a boy whose home is overrun with hungry beings. Can’t remember if they’re little dragons or gnomes or ogres, but they  ransack the place while eating every food scrap they discover. Everything from eggplants to peanut butter straight from the jar are consumed, and it’s utter chaos in the house. The boy finally gets all the hungry creatures out of the house, but he’s saved one cookie or muffin for himself. The book ends with the very last creature giving the boy’s treat a happy side-eye on its way out the door, which is in direct contrast to the book’s text indicating that the boy was finally rid of them. My son used to love this book and I’d love to find another copy. Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Please read the [tag wiki for identification requests](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and [edit your question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/26268/edit) to add any further information that comes to mind based on the suggestions there. For example, when and where did you read this book? What language was it in? What did the physical book look like? etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the book you’re looking for is [*One Hungry Monster*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0316608041) by Susan Heyboer O’Keefe (illustrated by Lynn Munsinger). It’s a counting book, where the number of monsters in each page increases, culminating in ten hungry monsters around the table insisting that the boy “feed them quick.” He then gives them food, in decreasing (I think—it’s been a while since I read this to my kids) numbers, but at a more rapid pace (one number per line rather than per page spread, as I recall).

Comment: That is absolutely the correct book. Thank you so much for your time in replying!